# Using nvarchar(MAX) on a mobile device

Tags: .net, sql-server, compact-framework, nvarchar

We are developing apps in .NET (Compact) Framework 2.0 for desktops and PPC devices running either WinCE or WinMobile 6.5

Recently we started using SQL Server 2005 and its new feature, nvarchar(max). All works fine on desktops. But on PPCs, we get the following problem:

The ParameterSize must be specified as -1 for nvarchar(max) SQL parameters. This works fine on desktops (full framework 2.0), but on the PPC, exception occurs:

System.ArgumentException : Invalid parameter Size value -1. The value must be greater than or equal to 0.

I think we have a proper CAB file installed for working with SQL Server from the mobile device (found in Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Mobile Edition Device SDK, named something like sql.wce5.armv4i.cab), but I cannot test this right now as I don't have the device.

The question is: Is nvarchar(max) supported on Compact Framework 2.0, SQL Server 2005 mobile device platform or not? How do I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

nvarchar(max) is not supported on SQL Server Compact.
See this link: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424%28SQL.110%29.aspx)

You can use ntext instead.

Comment: We're not using SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0, we use full SQL Server 2005 (all editions), using Microsoft's own data provider to access it. And it all points to it not supporting it either.

Comment: You cant use the full SQL Server on a windows mobile. MS SQL server 2005 mobile edition is just a older version of SQL Compact edition as far as i know. And yea, non of the compact (mobile) editions support nvarchar(max)